# Why is the constellation Capricornus depicted as a sea-goat?

Tags: zodiac, iconography

The [constellation Capricornus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capricornus) is often represented in the form of a sea-goat:

[image: "Capricornus", plate 25 in Urania's Mirror, a set of celestial cards accompanied by A familiar treatise on astronomy ... by Jehoshaphat Aspin. London. Astronomical chart, 1 print on layered paper board: etching, hand-colored.]

Why is that? Are there tales that attempt to explain how this curious hybrid came to be?

Answer (score -1):

One story from Greek Mythology tells of a sea goat Pricus. He shared the ability of time with Chronos(primordial god of time) and Kronos(titan of time). His children were like him. The sea goat were intellectual, honorable and favored by the gods. One day, a few of his kids are drawn to shore, pulling themselves up with their goat legs and metamorphosed into normal goats. Pricus is saddened by this, as he is their father, and reverses time. No matter how many time he does this, or rules he puts down, they still go to shore and Pricus realizes it is inevitable. The now normal goats travel away from the shore, out of sight and is saddened greatly more. Eventually he is all alone and begs Chronos to die, but he places him is the sky as Capricorn so he can watch over his children on the mountains.

Comment: This all sounds very interesting. Do you think it would be possible to point us to an ancient Greek source discussing Pricus?

Comment: @yannis I think this is the place I found my info. http://www.gods-and-monsters.com/capricorn-mythology.html